# Sort props array on child component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to sort an array of objects that comes from the props on a child component.

However, my sort method `Throw`s an error. Maybe I am not using the method properly or I can't properly determine the arguments that needs to be passed to it.

What I am trying to do is to sort according to the arguments passed using the click function and calling a method to execute the sort.

The intention here is when I click the arrow on the name, I can then sort it by name, according to the arrow (asc or desc).

This is my component ApplicationsList.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-backdrop">
    <div class="modal">
      <header class="modal-header">
        <slot name="header">
          <h3>{{job.name}}</h3>

          <button v-if="application.name" type="button" class="btn-close" @click="back">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="close">
            x
          </button>
        </slot>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
              <div v-if="!application.name" class=" col-12 applications-list">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name &nbsp;
                                <i @click="changeSort('name', 'desc')" v-if="this.sortBy === 'name' && this.sortDirection === 'asc' " class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
                                <i @click="changeSort('name', 'asc')" v-if="this.sortBy === 'name' && this.sortDirection === 'desc' " class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
                            </th>
                            <th>Email &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-unsorted"></i></th>
                            <th>Date &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-unsorted"></i></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="application-row" v-for="application in job.applications" :key="application.id" :application="application" @click="getApplication(application)">
                            <td>{{application.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{application.email}}</td>
                            <td>Applied {{moment(application.created_at).fromNow()}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div v-if="application.name" class="col-12 applicant">
                <small>Applied {{moment(application.created_at).fromNow()}}</small>
                <h4 v-if="application.name">Name</h4><p>{{application.name}}</p>
                <h4 v-if="application.email">Email</h4><p>{{application.email}}</p>
                <h4 v-if="application.phone">Phone</h4><p>{{application.phone}}</p>
                <h4 v-if="application.linkedin">Linkedin</h4><p>{{application.linkedin}}</p>
                <h4 v-if="application.cover_letter">Coverletter</h4><p v-html="application.cover_letter"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-footer">
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>

import moment from 'moment';

export default {

    name: 'ApplicationsList',

    props:['job'],

    data(){
        return{
            application: {name:'', email: '', created_at:'', phone: '', linkedin: '', cover_letter: ''},
            sortBy:'name',
            sortDirection:'asc',
        }
    },

    methods:{

        moment,

        close(){
            this.$emit('closeApplicationsRequest');
        },

        getApplication(application){
            this.application = application;
        },

        back(){
            this.application = '';
        },

        changeSort(sortBy, sortDirection){

            return this.job.application.sort((a, b) => a.sortBy - b.sortBy)

        }

    },


}

</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got two problems there:

### 1. Wrong [Property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

You are using *dot notation* on your sort function, which means you are trying to access the literal `sortBy` property of your objects.

What you want, instead, is *bracket notation*, which allows you to pass a variable to the accessor and, as such, get a dynamically set property. E.g.

```
const obj = {
 prop1: "value"
};

const myProp = "prop1";

obj.myProp; // undefined;
obj[myProp]; // "value"
```

### 2. Wrong comparison function

You are subtracting two strings from one another, which returns `NaN`. The sorting function cannot work like this. Instead, the comparison function needs to return either 0, lower than 0, or greater than 0.

<kbd>[More information here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)</kbd>

### Working code

```
function changeSort(sortBy) {
  return this.job.application
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if(a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) return -1;
      if(a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
}
```

---

#### Extra

I see in your code that you want to add a sorting order, but that wasn't implemented in the function. You could either do:

```
function changeSort(sortBy, sortDirection) {
  const alphabeticalApplications = this.job.application
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if(a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) return -1;
      if(a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) return 1;
      return 0;
    });

  return sortDirection === "asc" ? alphabeticalApplications
   : alphabeticalApplications.reverse();
}
```

or

```
function changeSort(sortBy, sortDirection) {
  const sortMultiplier = sortDirection === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
  return this.job.application
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if(a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) return -1 * sortMultiplier;
      if(a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) return 1 * sortMultiplier;
      return 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but i didn't understand completely your explanation. When you mention the first part, how can i transform the props that come from the parent component and that is displayed on the table on a object that can be used inside the sorting function?

Comment: If i try to execute the function straight in such way this throws an sort undefined error: job.applications OR this.job.applications > then .sort...rest of the function

Comment: I saw your comments, but I saw you accepted the answer. Did you manage to make it work or you need more clarification? I don't 100% understand your questions to be honest.